# memory issue with wowza server

Tags: linux, vps

I have installed the WowzaMediaServer on VPS which is also use for LAMP hosting. After starting wowza as Linux service I am running into memory issues as output of *free -m* suggest:

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          1024       1024          0          0          0          0
-/+ buffers/cache:       1024          0
Swap:            0          0          0
```

Running *top* gives me following insight:

```
  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
15984 root      19   0 11304 1412 1216 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.00 WowzaMediaServe
15986 root      19   0 9826m 104m  11m S  0.0 10.2   0:08.16 java
16242 root      15   0 14892 1220  996 R  0.0  0.1   0:00.00 top
```

As the output of top suggest the command java is taking most of the memory resources,so my question from community is should I go for more memory or can this be done some other way? Currently I have 1GB of memory.

Comment: Java is using 10% memory, try sorting top by mem usage to see where the rest is going.

Comment: In any case, the 0% free indicates that you have memory problems. Do as @terdon's comment suggests, but start thinking on more RAM (or at least adding swap space, if the memory use isn't performance critical).